# What is the best approach for uploading Typedoc documentation in confluence?

Tags: typescript, python-sphinx, confluence, typedoc

I have to automate my typedoc documentation so that i can directly upload it to the confluence page. I have already tried Sphinx however typedoc does not generates RST file which is needed by sphinx

Comment: Supposedly sphinx-js supports TypeDoc's json output, I haven't used it though, and it's seen very little traffic in the past few years, no idea if it still works since it was based on typedoc's output from 2018, and lots has changed since then... https://github.com/mozilla/sphinx-js

Answer (score 0):

There are such options:

- using Universal Wiki Converter (https://valiantys.com/en/blog/agility/universal-wiki-converter-transfer-wiki-content-confluence, https://github.com/AtlassianContribs/universal-wiki-converter). It has predefined parsing and rendering of some Wiki, but you will have to configure some scheduled tasks as scripts (e.g. bash or in python) to perform this
- Write the app that will render the Typedoc docs and parse them into JSON or XML and create/update content in Confluence via REST API (also .txt files will do)
- Using Confluence Java API for Word import (it laso supports other simple formats) to customize transferring of content from docs into Cofluence pages.
- Using WebDav to locate the .txt (HTML) format directly to pages location in files system https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-a-webdav-client-for-confluence-148044.html?_ga=2.219870169.1915395419.1564984609-1166064513.1559713737. NOTE that WebDav has security issues declared from Atlassian